# iOS SKMaps downloaded map package not showing in offline mode

Tags: package, offline, skmaps

I have downloaded a country map package following the documentation (http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec29). I added it successfully (`SKAddPackageResultSuccess`), stopped the app, relaunched it in airplane mode and no information was shown when zooming in that country.

I am using:

- SKMaps 2.5.1
- iOS 9.2 Simulator and iOS 9.2.1 iPhone 6.

Are there any other settings that I have to make in order for the `SKMapView` to use the downloaded package? I have set

```
SKMapsInitSettings* initSettings = [[SKMapsInitSettings alloc] init];
initSettings.mapDetailLevel = SKMapDetailLevelFull;
initSettings.connectivityMode = SKConnectivityModeOffline;

[[SKMapsService sharedInstance] initializeSKMapsWithAPIKey:kSKMapsAPIKey
                                                  settings:initSettings];
```

and I have a valid API key.

Thank you!

Comment: The SDK requires some meta files to be present in order to be able to render the map (in offline). Check this: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec28a

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [SylviA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3871963/sylvia) and the SKMaps technical support mentioned, I had to use the meta files, as described at [developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec28a](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec28a).